# Run npm command from google cloud function

Tags: sequelize.js

I currently have a react js website using cloud functions as rest API. Those functions connect to an SQL instance using a private IP.

For the SQL orm I use Sequelize and so far so good, however, I did a migration and I cannot make it run on the SQL instance. Is there any way to run the migration via npm command? I tried to use Umzug but it doesn't look like working as the function keeps timing out.

Answer (score 1):

After trying different options, I found the solutions was way more simple than I thought. The way to execute npm commands and resolve my issue:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {

try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const migrate = exec(
            'npx sequelize-cli db:migrate',
            err => (err ? reject(err) : resolve())
        );

        // Forward stdout+stderr to this process
        migrate.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
        migrate.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
    });
} catch (e) {
    res.code(500);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(e));
}
};
```